# Docusign pre-filled tabs

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

We are trying to pre-fill PDF forms in Docusign so that clients only need to sign the template as we already have all the data needed to complete the form.

We are able to send the template via Docusign programmatically but when we test, the Text fields that we place on the form do not show for the signer. They are not pre-filled and do not even show up as fields. They are blank and the signer has to drag a field onto the form.

We are using Node.js

As an example, we have created a Text Field named "client-fullname" on the PDF form within the template.

Programatically, we are doing this:

```
const tabClientFullName = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({ tabLabel: 'client-fullname', value: 'John Q Smith' });

const dsTabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
      textTabs: [
        tabClientFullName
      ]
    });

const signer1 = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
      email: signerEmail,
      name: signerName,
      roleName: 'signer',
      tabs: dsTabs
});

env.templateRoles = [signer1];
env.status = 'sent'; // We want the envelope to be sent
```

What are we missing?

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all, you can put the tabs on the template directly. Not filled out, but just place them there, so that all you have to do in the API is fill them.

{This code below shows different types of tabs, not just text.}

So, when the template has tabs, the code to fill them is like this:
(note each tabs has a `tabLabel` property)

```
// create the envelope definition with the template id
  let envelopeDefinition = docusign.EnvelopeDefinition.constructFromObject({
    templateId: args.templateId,
    status: "sent",
  });

  // Set the values for the fields in the template
  // List item
  let list1 = docusign.List.constructFromObject({
    value: "green",
    documentId: "1",
    pageNumber: "1",
    tabLabel: "list",
  });

  // Checkboxes
  let check1 = docusign.Checkbox.constructFromObject({
      tabLabel: "ckAuthorization",
      selected: "true",
    }),
    check3 = docusign.Checkbox.constructFromObject({
      tabLabel: "ckAgreement",
      selected: "true",
    });
  // The NOde.js SDK has a bug so it cannot create a Number tab at this time.
  //number1 = docusign.Number.constructFromObject({
  //    tabLabel: "numbersOnly", value: '54321'});
  let radioGroup = docusign.RadioGroup.constructFromObject({
    groupName: "radio1",
    // You only need to provide the radio entry for the entry you're selecting
    radios: [
      docusign.Radio.constructFromObject({ value: "white", selected: "true" }),
    ],
  });
  let text = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
    tabLabel: "text",
    value: "Jabberwocky!",
  });

  // We can also add a new tab (field) to the ones already in the template:
  let textExtra = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
    document_id: "1",
    page_number: "1",
    x_position: "280",
    y_position: "172",
    font: "helvetica",
    font_size: "size14",
    tab_label: "added text field",
    height: "23",
    width: "84",
    required: "false",
    bold: "true",
    value: args.signerName,
    locked: "false",
    tab_id: "name",
  });

  // Pull together the existing and new tabs in a Tabs object:
  let tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
    checkboxTabs: [check1, check3], // numberTabs: [number1],
    radioGroupTabs: [radioGroup],
    textTabs: [text, textExtra],
    listTabs: [list1],
  });
  // Create the template role elements to connect the signer and cc recipients
  // to the template
  let signer = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
    email: args.signerEmail,
    name: args.signerName,
    roleName: "signer",
    clientUserId: args.signerClientId, // change the signer to be embedded
    tabs: tabs, // Set tab values
  });
  // Create a cc template role.
  let cc = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
    email: args.ccEmail,
    name: args.ccName,
    roleName: "cc",
  });
  // Add the TemplateRole objects to the envelope object
  envelopeDefinition.templateRoles = [signer, cc];
  // Create an envelope custom field to save the our application's
  // data about the envelope
  let customField = docusign.TextCustomField.constructFromObject({
      name: "app metadata item",
      required: "false",
      show: "true", // Yes, include in the CoC
      value: "1234567",
    }),
    customFields = docusign.CustomFields.constructFromObject({
      textCustomFields: [customField],
    });
  envelopeDefinition.customFields = customFields;

  return envelopeDefinition;
```

https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/lib/eSignature/examples/setTemplateTabValues.js

Comment: How is this different from what we are doing?

Comment: First of all, do you have the tabs in the template?
Second, do you set tabLabel?

Comment: yes and yes. We have looked at the same example you have posted and are following it quite closely.

Comment: This example works for me, are you saying running this example does not work for you?

Comment: Note that if you run the Launcher, it creates the template for you, if you use that template - it works

Answer (score 0):

We figured it out. The role 'signer' must match the role used to place forms on the template PDF. Once we changed the role name, everything worked correctly.